# Parse data from JSON in ReactJS

Tags: json, parsing, reactjs, fetch

I have data like this:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "abridged_cast": [
        {
          "characters": [
            "Dominic Toretto"
          ],
          "id": "162652472",
          "name": "Vin Diesel"
        },
        {
          "characters": [
            "Brian O'Conner"
          ],
          "id": "162654234",
          "name": "Paul Walker"
        },
        {
          "characters": [
            "Louie Tran"
          ],
          "id": "162684066",
          "name": "Tony Jaa"
        },
        {
          "characters": [
            "Deckard Shaw"
          ],
          "id": "162653720",
          "name": "Jason Statham"
        },
        {
          "characters": [
            "Luke Hobbs"
          ],
          "id": "770893686",
          "name": "Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson"
        }
      ],
      "alternate_ids": {
        "imdb": "2820852"
      },
      "critics_consensus": "",
      "id": "771354922",
      "links": {
        "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/furious_7/",
        "cast": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771354922/cast.json",
        "reviews": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771354922/reviews.json",
        "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771354922.json",
        "similar": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771354922/similar.json"
      },
      "mpaa_rating": "PG-13",
      "posters": {
        "detailed": "http://resizing.flixster.com/pVDoql2vCTzNNu0t6z0EUlE5G_c=/51x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/18/14/11181482_ori.jpg",
        "original": "http://resizing.flixster.com/pVDoql2vCTzNNu0t6z0EUlE5G_c=/51x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/18/14/11181482_ori.jpg",
        "profile": "http://resizing.flixster.com/pVDoql2vCTzNNu0t6z0EUlE5G_c=/51x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/18/14/11181482_ori.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "http://resizing.flixster.com/pVDoql2vCTzNNu0t6z0EUlE5G_c=/51x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/18/14/11181482_ori.jpg"
      },
      "ratings": {
        "audience_rating": "Upright",
        "audience_score": 88,
        "critics_rating": "Certified Fresh",
        "critics_score": 82
      },
      "release_dates": {
        "theater": "2015-04-03"
      },
      "runtime": 140,
      "synopsis": "Continuing the global exploits in the unstoppable franchise built on speed, Vin Diesel, Paul Walker and Dwayne Johnson lead the returning cast of Fast & Furious 7. James Wan directs this chapter of the hugely successful series that also welcomes back favorites Michelle Rodriguez, Jordana Brewster, Tyrese Gibson, Chris \"Ludacris\" Bridges, Elsa Pataky and Lucas Black. They are joined by international action stars new to the franchise including Jason Statham, Djimon Hounsou, Tony Jaa, Ronda Rousey and Kurt Russell.",
      "title": "Furious 7",
      "year": 2015
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to parse all data from all fields from this JSON file. Is there a way to do it in React JS? Could you please suggest me any way to parse data from a structured JSON file like this?

Comment: use ajax to fetch the file. jQuery has a getJSON command

Comment: Could you please do me an example using AJAX? With ReactJS, I have to write in JSX

Comment: Does your code use the keyword 'fetch'?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

React lives in JavaScript. So parsing a JSON string is done with:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myjsonstring);
```

How to fetch a file from somewhere with AJAX is a different question.

You could use `fetch()` for this. See for example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API or
https://davidwalsh.name/fetch or
https://blog.gospodarets.com/fetch_in_action

Comment: I thought React lives in JSX?!

Comment: No, React is written in JavaScript. Your react code is JavaScript also. (Therefore all your filenames end with .js)  You put jsx inside react. The <div> etc inside your react code is jsx. This is translated to JavaScript also.

Comment: @necroface please tag this answer as "accepted" if you're happy with the answer :)