# Turn array of objects into list of options having label and value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to transform a JSON object to be a specific structure so it feeds into a select tag.

I tested it outside the codebase and it worked, but now I don't know where the problem is. My select tag still appears empty

Here is the example [select bar](https://codesandbox.io/s/72j69vnk1x?file=/src/index.js:326-481)

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wildflower-ju8pn?file=/helper/index.js:265-576)

Here is the structure I need:

```
const options = [
  { value: "Alabama A & M University", label: "Alabama A & M University" },
  { value: "Amridge University", label: "Amridge University" },
  { value: "University of Alabama at Birmingham", label: "University of Alabama at Birmingham" }
];
```

a array of objects with value and label keys

Here is the  original structure:

```
const institutions = [
    {
      "institution": "Alabama A & M University"
    },
    {
      "institution": "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
    },
    {
      "institution": "Amridge University"
    }]
```

Here is how I am manipulating the code:

```
export const transformCollegeJSON =(institutions = [])=> {
  let result = [];

    for(let k = 0; k <= institutions.length; k++){   
            result.push({
            "value":institutions[college]['institution'],
            "label":institutions[college]['institution']
        })
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: have a look at `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: hmm, you can use that ```var myObject = JSON.parse(myjsonstring);
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794062/parse-data-from-json-in-reactjs

Comment: It seems `college` does not have any value. Try replacing `college` by `k`

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```js
const src = [
    {
      "institution": "Alabama A & M University"
    },
    {
      "institution": "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
    },
    {
      "institution": "Amridge University"
    }],
    
    result = src.map(({institution:value}) => ({value, label:value}))
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is the answer I would have given. I can't really improve on it either, concise, and gets it done.

Comment: I played around with your answer, it solve the structure question, but it doesn't show up in OP select.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code to work, replace `<=` by `<` in the `for` parenthesis and replace `college` by `k`

```js
const transformCollegeJSON = (institutions = []) => {
    let result = [];

    for (let k = 0; k < institutions.length; k++) {
        result.push({
            "value": institutions[k]['institution'],
            "label": institutions[k]['institution']
        })
    }
    return result
}

const institutions = [{
        "institution": "Alabama A & M University"
    },
    {
        "institution": "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
    },
    {
        "institution": "Amridge University"
    }
]

console.log(transformCollegeJSON(institutions))
```