# Build list checkbox options with id, value, label from array of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

I am using React and Typescript,

I have to build the React component **MultiSelectCheckBoxes** by passing to the constructor an **array of Objects** of type Color:

A checkbox list need a structure like this:

```
const options = [{
   "id": 1,
   "value": "9ce42304-b732-4791-9731-6f299b6df8c7",
   "label": "Blue"
}, {
   "id": 2,
   "value": "90419f06-7d07-45c8-bcec-d675096fe27f",
   "label": "Violet"
}]
```

And this is my input (from the dev console) :

```
  {colors: Array(2)}
      0:
        color:  {
        
           "name": "Blue",
           "id": "9ce42304-b732-4791-9731-6f299b6df8c7"
        }

     1:
        color:  {
        
           "name": "Violet",
           "id": "90419f06-7d07-45c8-bcec-d675096fe27f"
        }
  }
```

I need something like in this post, but with Typescript, so with the clear type of the objects:

*Similar question:* [Turn array of objects into list of options having label and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232592/turn-array-of-objects-into-list-of-options-having-label-and-value)

Full code work in progress:

```
import ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes from "react-multiselect-checkboxes";

import { Color } from '@org/colors';

interface MultiSelectProps {

    colors: Color[]

 }

 const MultiSelect = ({colors} : MultiSelectProps): JSX.Element => {

     // HERE BUILD THE options FROM colors 
     // my attempts:
     // colors.forEach(item => option_obj[item.color.id] = item.color.name) ??????
     //const test = JSON.stringify({colors}) ????????

     return ( 
         <ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes options={options} /> ) }

     export default MultiSelect
```

Edit:

if I try

```
   colors.forEach(item => obj[item.color.id] = item.color.name)
```

I get this error from Typescript

```
 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'
```

Comment: "*I need something like in this post, but with Typescript,*" lucky for you, TS is a superset of JS. So valid JS should be valid TS.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, because Typescript is asking me the type, and the error I get is this:  `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'`

Comment: If you were to solve the error, you might realise the code doesn't work but it's *not* because it's JS or TS but because TS rightfully points out the logic is potentially incorrect.

Comment: Ok, and how to build this list of options, from that array ? I am a python dev, I have a lot of difficulties on understanding Typescript, this is my second day with this O__O

Comment: [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found, and that it works:

```
import ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes from "react-multiselect-checkboxes";

import { Color } from '@org/colors';

interface MultiSelectProps {

     colors: Color[]

 }

 const MultiSelect = ({colors} : MultiSelectProps): JSX.Element => {

   let res: Object[] = []


    for (let k=0; k< colors.length; k++){
    res.push({ 
     "id": colors[k].color.id,
     "value" : colors[k].color.id,
     "label": colors[k].color.name 

  })
 }

 return ( 
     <ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes options={res} /> ) }

 export default MultiSelect
```

Where I simply build an array of Objects.

Color is a property of the Object Color.

The result is this dropdown menu, a ReactMultiSelectCheckBoxes
built dynamically from a list of Objects.

[image]